# Show that the sequence $a_n$ is eventually periodic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Suppose that $a_0, a_1, \cdots $ and $b_0, b_1, \cdots$ are two sequences of positive integers such that $a_0, b_0 \ge 2$ and $$ a_{n+1} = \gcd{(a_n, b_n)} + 1, \qquad b_{n+1} = \operatorname{lcm}{(a_n, b_n)} - 1. $$ Show that the sequence $a_n$ is eventually periodic; in other words, there exist integers $N \ge 0$ and $t > 0$ such that $a_{n+t} = a_n$ for all $n \ge N$.

Hint: Try to prove the sequence is bounded above.

Can someone explain to me how showing the sequence bounded above completed the proof? I have not got that part.

Here is my progress.

Note that $a_i\ge 2$. Moreover, $a_i\ge a_{i+1}$ whenever $a_i\not \mid b_i$. When $a_i|b_i\implies a_{i+1}=a_i+1, b_{i+1}=b_i-1$.

Call a number $a_i$ good if $a_i<a_{i+1}$. Note that a sequence can not have an infinite subsequence containing good numbers.

Hence, there will be a subsequence such that $$(a,b)\rightarrow (a-c,d+c)\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow (a-1,d+1) \rightarrow (a,d)\rightarrow (X,Y).$$
(else the sequence $a_i$ would be bounded above by $a$, which would solve the problems)

So, now, consider the sequence $$(a,b)\rightarrow (a-c,d+c)\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow (a-1,d+1) \rightarrow (a,d)\rightarrow (X,Y).$$

Note that $$\gcd(a,b)+1=a-c, \text{lcm}(a,b)-1=d+c\implies $$
Note that $$(a,d)=(a+d,a), a-c|d+c\implies a-c|a+d.$$

I want to try and prove that $X=a-c$ i.e show that $(a,d)=a-c+1$. But I do not know how to. Any hints or solution, in this direction?

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%5Cgcd(a_n%2C%20b_n)%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24b_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D(a_n%2C%20b_n)-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aperiodic%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [lcm/gcd sequence](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1268845p6622169) (with quite a few posts), as well as the thread [number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1615219p10095743) stating this is from "N$4$ from IMO Shortlist $2015$" and linking to the first thread.

Comment: Yes, I saw the thread, but there isn't many solutions, explaining why bounding is sufficient.

Comment: If you can show that both sequences are bounded by some integer $M > 0$ (and you really only need to show $b_n$ is bounded above), you know that $(a_n, b_n) \in \{1, \ldots, M\} \times \{1, \ldots, M\}$ for all $n$, which is a finite set. Pigeonhole priniciple says that $(a_{n + k}, b_{n + k}) = (a_n, b_n)$ for some $n, k$ and the first order recursive nature of the sequence says that the sequences would have to repeat every $k$ thereafter. I don't see how to show $b_n$ is bounded though.

Comment: @TheoBendit $b_n$ bounded is not necessary ( not true also). We just have to show $a_n$ bounded.

Comment: Just a hint: Let $a_0 = md$, $b_0 = ld$ where $(l,m) = 1$. 

Now $a_1 = d +1, b_1 = mld - 1$.

Assume $gcd(a_1, b_1) = a_1$. Then $a_2 = d + 2, b_2 = mld - 2$.

If we kept going, we will end up with $a_{m-1} = d + (m-1)d = md, b_{m-1} = mld - (m-1)d$. 

But now $gcd(a_{m-1}, b_{m-1}) = d$ and so $a_n$ does not increase forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going just to review and post some mentioned ideas together, with more explanation, in a way that might be helpful to readers:

What we need is to show that the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, ...$ is bounded. Let's call $a_i$ "a peak" if $a_i\geq a_{i+1}$. As it is noticed above, if $a_i$ is not a peak, then $(a_{i+1}, b_{i+1})=(a_i+1,b_i-1)$.

Now, assume $a_m$ and $a_n$ are two consecutive peaks ($n\gt m $).

First we prove that $a_m\ge a_n$.

If $a_m\lt a_n$, then $(a_{m+1},b_{m+1})=(d+1, dxy-1)$ where $a_m=dx, b_m=dy $, and $ gcd(x,y)=1$ (simply because $a_{m+1}$ is not a peak).  Since $a_m\lt a_n$ (by assumption), we can arrive at an index, namely $j$, where $m\lt j\lt n$, and $(a_j,b_j)=(dx, dxy-dx+d).$ The reason behind this claim is obvious. Just notice that none of the indices between $m$ and $n$ is a peak, so at each step $a_i$ is increased by $1$ and $b_i$ is decreased by $1$ and this process can be repeated $dx-d-1$ times as $dx= a_m\lt a_n$. But this is a contradiction because, in this manner,  $a_{j+1}=d+1$, which means $a_j$ is a peak (We had supposed $a_m$ and $a_n$ were two consecutive peaks).

Therefore, the subsequesnce of all peaks will be eventually constant, and this imply that the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, ...$ is bounded because it is impossible to have infinite non-peaks between two consecutive peaks (otherwise for some $i$, $b_i\lt2$).

Now, let $C$ be the maximum of the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, ...$ and $N=C!$, then the pair $(a_n, b_n\; mod\;N)$ determines the pair $(a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}\; mod\;N)$ (Just because $gcd(a_n,b_n)=gcd(a_n, b_n\; mod\; N)$). As the sequence  $a_0, a_1, a_2, ...$ is bounded and $b_n\; mod\;N$ is limited, we will finally get the pair $(a_n, b_n\; mod\;N)$ somewhere repeated, which means the sequence is periodic.